# Determinant formula and invertibility.

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, determinant

I am working on a problem where I need to find the determinant of
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
b & a & & \\
  & b & a \\
  &   &   & \ddots \\
  &   &   &  &  & a \\
a &   &   &  & & b
\end{bmatrix}
$$
this matrix. I found $b^n-a^n$ if $n$ is even and $b^n+a^n$ if $n$ is odd. The text then asks for the values of $a$ and $b$ for which the matrix is noninvertible. They then say (*hint:* remember complex numbers). Is it necessary to consider complex numbers since $b^n=a^n \Longrightarrow b=a$ or $b=-a$ in the case of $n$ even and $b^n = -a^n \Longrightarrow b=-a$ for $n$ odd?

Comment: It is necessary to consider complex numbers exactly because the implications in your last sentence _do not hold_ when $a,b$ are allowed to be complex numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First deal with the case $a = b = 0$.

Now if $a \ne 0 \ne b$, you have $b^{n} - a^{n} = 0$ if and only if $b^{n} = a^{n}$ if and only if $(a b^{-1})^{n} = 1$, so $a b^{-1}$ is an $n$-th root of unity in $\Bbb{C}$...

Comment: I do not know what an $n^{\text{th}}$ root of unity is (I looked it up, but I cannot use this knowledge). However, I see where my reasoning is incorrect.

Comment: @5space, if you cannot use that, then I am not sure what is required of you. But, wait, what are $a, b$ supposed to be? I assumed from your question that they were bona fide complex numbers. Or are they real?

Comment: Throughout most of the text, we assume that matrices have entries in $\mathbb{R}$. But the book will occasionally throw in problems involving $\mathbb{C}$. For this particular problem, it is not explicitly stated either way, except for the hint.